# Android Cordova Plugin Development - Errors in JS Interface

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm attempting to develop a Cordova plugin for the Android platform, and admittedly this is my first one so my mistakes are probably elementary, but for the life of me I can't figure out why my cordova plugin just won't work. I keep getting reference errors like the following:

`"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/pdfRenderer.js (3)`

`"Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (10)`

As well as this TypeError
`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (37)`

Here's my Plugin Java code:

```
package com.dev.plugin.PdfRendererService;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.Page;

/**
 * This class handles a pdf file called from JavaScript and converts a 
selected page (default is first) to a byte array representing a bitmap.
 */
public class PdfRendererService extends CordovaPlugin {

private ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
private PdfRenderer renderer = null;
private Page currentPage = null;

private int mWidth = 400, mHeight = 600;
private String mRenderMode = "display";

@Override
public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView){        
    super.initialize(cordova, webView);
}

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    this.validatePermissions();

    boolean isPageOpen = false;
    switch(action){
        case "open":
            return executeOpen(args, callbackContext);
        case "renderPage":
            return executeRenderPage(args, callbackContext);
        case "pageCount":
            callbackContext.success(this.getPageCount());
            return true;
        case "close":
            this.closeRenderer();
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean executeOpen(JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext){
    //TODO - Implement this method
    return true;
}

private boolean executeRenderPage(JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext){
    //TODO - Implement this method
    return true;
}

private int getPageCount() {
    if(renderer == null)
        return 0;

    return renderer.getPageCount();
}

private void initializeWriteFileDescriptor(String filePath, CallbackContext callbackContext){
    //TODO - Implement this method
}

private void initializeRenderer(String filePath, CallbackContext callbackContext){
    renderer = null;

    initializeWriteFileDescriptor(filePath, callbackContext);

    if(fileDescriptor == null) {
        callbackContext.error("An error has occurred while loading the requested file.");
        return;
    }

    renderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
}

private void closeRenderer() {
    if(renderer == null) {
        return;
    }

    renderer.close();
}

private boolean openPage(int index, CallbackContext callbackContext){
    //TODO - Implement this method
    return true;
}

private void sendBitmapAsBytes(int index, Bitmap bitmap, CallbackContext callbackContext){
    //TODO - Implement this method
}

private static byte[] toByteArray(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, stream);

    return stream.toByteArray();
}

private static Bitmap getBitmap(int width, int height){
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}

private static ParcelFileDescriptor getWriteFileDescriptor(String filePath){
    return ParcelFileDescriptor(
            new File(filePath),
            ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_TRUNCATE |
            ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_CREATE   |
            ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_WRITE_ONLY
    );
}
}
```

My Javascript Plugin interface (pdfRenderer.js)

```
'use strict';

var cordova = require('cordova');

var PLUGIN_NAME = "PdfRendererService";

var SERVICE_OPEN = "open";
var SERVICE_CLOSE = "close";
var SERVICE_PAGE_COUNT = "pageCount";
var SERVICE_RENDER_PAGE = "renderPage";

var RENDER_MODE_DISPLAY = "display";
var RENDER_MODE_PRINT = "print";

var PdfRendererPlugin = {
display: function(filePath, callback){
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }, PLUGIN_NAME, SERVICE_OPEN, [filePath, RENDER_MODE_DISPLAY]);
},

renderPage: function(pageNo, callback){
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }, PLUGIN_NAME, SERVICE_RENDER_PAGE, [pageNo]);
},

close: function(callback){
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }, PLUGIN_NAME, SERVICE_CLOSE, []);
},

getPageCount: function(callback){
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }, PLUGIN_NAME, SERVICE_PAGE_COUNT, []);
}
};

module.exports = PdfRendererPlugin;
```

index.js

```
var testFilePath = 'assets/software-development.pdf';

var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
},

// deviceready Event Handler
//
// Bind any cordova events here. Common events are:
// 'pause', 'resume', etc.
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.display();
},

display: function(){
    PdfRendererPlugin.display(testFilePath, function(data){
    console.log('Bitmap Bytes');
        console.log(data);
    });
}
};

app.initialize();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cordova PDF Generator Plugin Test</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,
          maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width,
          height=device-height" />
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Cordova PDF Generation Plugin Test</h1>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pdfRenderer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="cordova-plugin-pdf-renderer" version="0.2.3">
<name>PdfRenderer</name>
<description>Cordova PDF Renderer Plugin</description>
<license>MIT</license>
<keywords>cordova,pdf,renderer</keywords>

<platform name="android">
    <js-module src="www/js/pdfRenderer.js" name="PdfRendererPlugin">
        <runs/>

        <clobbers target="PdfRendererPlugin" />
    </js-module>

    <config-file target="config.xml" parent="/*">
        <feature name="PdfRendererPlugin">
            <param name="android-package" value="com.dev.plugin.PdfRendererService"/>
            <param name="onload" value="true" />
        </feature>
    </config-file>

    <source-file src="src/android/PdfRendererService.java" target-dir="src/com/dev/plugin/" />
</platform>
</plugin>
```

Can anybody help me figure out why I'm getting these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can't require the Cordova module directly.
What happens is, when you plugin is installed to the Android platform, the Cordova CLI will wrap your JS plugin component in a function:

```
cordova.define("your.plugin.namespace", function(require, exports, module) {
// Your plugin code
});
```

Therefore, in your plugin code, you can assume `cordova` is already defined as a global variable, and `require`, `exports`, `module`.

So remove the line `var cordova = require('cordova');` from your `pdfRenderer.js`.

Also you should remove the `onload` handler from the body tag: `<body onload="initialize()">`.
This is not necessary as the `deviceready` event is what is being (and should be) used to kick off app initialization, and you already have this in your `app.js`

These are the two obvious errors that I can see, so try making these changes and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good start.

Here are my errors now:

`"Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/pdfRenderer.js (81)`

and

`"Class not found", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/pdfRenderer.js (16)`

Comment: `"Class not found", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/pdfRenderer.js (16)` This is because you have named your plugin `<feature name="PdfRendererPlugin">` but your are calling it as `PLUGIN_NAME = "PdfRendererService";`. It would be easiest to name all of the components of the plugin with the same name to avoid this type of issue.

Comment: I seem to be making more progress as a result of your advice, as well as removing any `console.log` calls in the error callbacks of the JS interface. I'm no longer getting these errors, but now when I attempt to call the plugin functions, I get the following error:

`D/PluginManager: exec() call to unknown plugin: PdfRendererPlugin`

This is coming from the android side, so it looks like the JS Interface is working. Perhaps I should close this thread and open a new one if there's not already an answer to my problem out there?

Comment: I recommend renaming everything that's currently `PdfRendererService` to `PdfRendererPlugin` so you have consistency between the JS-Java interface.